# Extra white space after knitting in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

I am trying to generate a table using `kableExtra` on the toy `iris` data. I am able to successfully generate my output in PDF but I get some white spaces after the 5th row.

```
set.seed(123)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
df<- slice_sample(iris, n = 10)

kbl(df, caption = "Iris dataset", booktabs = T) %>%
kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position"))
```

I couldn't find any trim flags or so that I can pass them to the `slice_sample`. Not sure why it persists or is it by design?

[image: kableExtra]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line spacing is a result of selecting `booktabs = TRUE` in the call to `kbl` which by  definition includes  '\addlinespace' in the default `linesep` argument every fifth row to make it easier to scan tables.

You can override this by setting `linesep = ""`. Or for that matter introduce spacing in any order you like.

```r
kbl(df, caption = "Iris dataset", booktabs = TRUE, linesep = "" ) %>%
kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position"))
```

[image]